# Qual a diferença de eu deixar um variável no protocol marcada com static ou sem static em Swift 4?

Tags: swift, static

Estou aprendendo sobre `protocol`s agora, e vi um trecho de código em Swift 4 que define um protocolo, segue abaixo o trecho do código.

```
protocol AnotherProtocol {
  static var someTypeProperty: Int { get set }
}
```

Perceba que a variável `someTypeProperty` está declarada como `static`, e neste outro caso abaixo ela aparece sem o `static`.

```
protocol AnotherProcol {
  var someTypeProperty: Int { get set }
}
```

Qual a diferença desses dois tipos de implementação de protocolo na linguagem Swift 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta específica para o protocolo parece indicar já saber porque usa-se o `static` em um tipo regular, como uma classe, por exemplo. O motivo é o mesmo, apenas difere que o protocolo é só a indicação de um contrato.

Um `static` indica que o membro é to tipo e não da instância. Usado no `protocol` ele indica que qualquer tipo que decida implementar este protocolo específico, no exemplo `AnotherProcol`, deverá obrigatoriamente ter uma propriedade chamada `someTypeProperty` do tipo `Int` com os métodos *acessor* e *mutador*. O protocolo não dia mais nada de como eles devem ser, no tipo concreto eles podem ter uma implementação de código se for o desejado, o protocolo só exige que exista a propriedade, não diz como ela deve proceder, se deve ter algum campo auxiliar, nada.

Comment: Não entendi muito não... então o Static não serve para nada ? Só pra indicar que a propriedade tem que ter get e set ? mas isso não é indicado logo após a declaração var variable:Int {get set} ?

Comment: Como eu falei, você sabe precisa saber o que é o `static` fora do do `protocol`, você sabe? Se não souber é melhor entender isso primeiro para depois tentar entender `protocol`. Quando tenta aprender as coisas fora de ordem fica mais difícil aprender qualquer coisa, por isso que eu sempre recomendo as pessoas irem por um caminho estruturado. Pegar coisas aleatórias nunca deu certo.

Comment: Eu sei o que é static no conceito de c#.. exemplo quando você define um método como static ele pode ser acessado sem uma instancia da classe.

Comment: Ok, vou considerar que sabe mesmo, sabe o que é a interface no C#?

Comment: Sim, já implementei interfaces no c#

Comment: Então, sabendo o que é o `static` e o que é `interface` do C#, é exatamente isso, só que em Swift a intercade que ela chama de protocolo aceita `static`, como o C# 8 aceitará também.

Comment: É se você for parar para pensar, protocolos tem o mesmo sentido de interface... Fazer requerimentos de métodos e atributos que devem ser implementados para quem adota.

Comment: Exatamente o que eu disse na resposta.

Comment: Você programa iOS ?

Comment: Nunca criei nada.